# Want to get Total count of records in datewise on the basis of unit id column - sql group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to get Total count of records in datewise on the basis of unit id column - sql group by clause

```
SELECT 
    count(t.Unit_ID) as Record_Count,
    t.Unit_ID,
    convert(date,t.Punch_Time) as Pdate 
FROM HRMS.dbo.Trans_Raw t
LEFT JOIN Device_Master d ON d.device_ID = t.Unit_ID
GROUP BY t.Unit_ID,convert(date,t.Punch_Time)
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT convert(date, t.Punch_Time) as Pdate, count(d.device_ID) as Record_Count
FROM HRMS.dbo.Trans_Raw T left join
     Device_Master D 
     ON d.device_ID = t.Unit_ID
GROUP BY convert(date, t.Punch_Time)
```

Comment: yes, but i want to see unit_id column also. pls help

Comment: @JoyalGeorge . . . Doesn't your query do that?